# Ciclo while dentro de mpdf

Tags: php, mpdf

Tengo un reporte que es de notas, pero al insertar este código

```
while($notas = mysql_fetch_assoc($r_notas)) {
     $html.='<td class="tdClass"><b>'.$notas['asignatura'].'</b></td>
             <td class="tdClass">'.$notas['nota_1'].'</td>
             <td class="tdClass">'.$notas['nota_2'].'</td>
             <td class="tdClass">'.$notas['nota_3'].'</td>
             <td class="tdClass">'.$notas['nota_4'].'</td>
             <td class="tdClass">'.$notas['nota_5'].'</td>
             <td class="tdClass">'.$notas['nota_6'].'</td>
             <td class="tdClass">'.$notas['nota_7'].'</td>
             <td class="tdClass">'.$notas['promedio'].'</td>';


              }
```

no me muestra las filas de la tabla, incluse probé haciendolo sin variables y lo hice con un texto cualquiera, pero no muestra nada, pero si hago otro ciclo como foreach me muestra las filas, pero en este caso no me sirve ese ciclo creo yo. No quiero colocar todo el código, porque es mucho, pero básicamente esa linea solamente es el problema.

Comment: Todo indica que en `$html` vas creando una tabla. ¿Esa tabla se construye bien, con sus etiquetas `<table>` y `</table>` al principio y al final?  Si la sacas por pantalla con `echo $html;` esa tabla se muestra? ¿Dónde está la línea de código donde finalmente muestras la variable `$html` una vez has terminado la concatenación?

Comment: si, muestra la cabecera de la tabla, todo eso bien, el único problema es ese while, que es como si no lo reconociera, por ende el cuerpo de la tabla no lo muestra, nada.

Comment: Tienes que verificar dos cosas: 1º. Que la tabla es correcta, o sea que por ejemplo tiene todas sus etiquetas, que no tiene más o menos columnas fuera del `while` (deberías mostrar la parte inicial de `$html` donde empiezas a crear la tabla, así como la parte final donde la cierras, fuera del `while)`;  2º. Puede que no haya datos  en `$r_notas` o que los valores como `$notas['nota_1']` no existan así. Eso lo puedes probar haciendo **`var_dump($r_notas);`** fuera del `while` o haciendo algo como `echo $notas['nota_1'];` dentro del `while`. No sé si me explico... debes depurar tus variables.

Comment: tiene datos, si lo hice sin un while y muestra datos, realmente tengo todas las etiquetas bien, el problema es el while, porque aunque no hubieses datos por lo menos me mostraria la estructura del body de la tabla, pero no me muestra nada, osea es como que el while está haciendo nada

Comment: ¿Si haces **`var_dump($r_notas);`**  antes del `while` qué muestra? ¿Puedes ponerlo aquí en comentario? Si usas `mysqli` debes poner **`mysqli_fetch_assoc `**, le faltaría una **`i`** ...

Comment: hare eso, te comento.

Comment: No se el resto.. pero $notas = mysql_fetch_assoc($r_notas) como condicion del while, es muy raro.. no deberia ser ==?

Comment: @gbianchi la sintaxis correcta es con un solo signo de  `=`, [como se puede ver en el Manual](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php), creo que **está usando la extensión vieja**, debería usar: **`while($notas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r_notas)) {`** o que **`$r_notas` está vacío**. Una de las dos.

Comment: una asignacion como condicion del while?

Comment: Sí @gbianchi, recuerda que estamos en PHP :) Es la forma de recorrer dentro de un `while` un conjunto de resultados. En cada iteracción, la fila de resultados adquiere el valor de `$notas` y se accede a cada columna invocando `$notas['columna1'], $notas['columna2']...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que estás usando la extensión antigua de `mysql` en vez de usar `mysqli`.

Aprovecho para proponer alguna mejora en el código:

```
$td_on='<td class="tdClass">';
$td_off='</td>';    
//var_dump($r_notas);
if($r_notas){
    while($notas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r_notas)) {
     $html.=$td_on.'<b>'.$notas['asignatura'].'</b>'.$td_off.
             $td_on.$notas['nota_1'].$td_off.
             $td_on.$notas['nota_2'].$td_off.
             $td_on.$notas['nota_3'].$td_off.
             $td_on.$notas['nota_4'].$td_off.
             $td_on.$notas['nota_5'].$td_off.
             $td_on.$notas['nota_6'].$td_off.
             $td_on.$notas['nota_7'].$td_off.
             $td_on.$notas['promedio'].$td_off;
      }
    //... resto del código      
}else{

    echo "No hay datos";
}
```